# How do I integrate Google Analytics in Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I integrate Google analytics with clients website and now, a client wants to track his mobile app as well. So, I want to know that how to integrate Google Analytics in Android app. I read this article,

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

This is enough for me and I just follow the instructions mentioned on above link given below?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that link should show you how to add analytics to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use these link 
For this Ready Project(Android Integrating Google Analytics V4)
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

Android Firebase – Integrating Analytics
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-firebase-integrate-analytics/